# Verification button not working AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to programming and I've made a math question generator in as3
But it doesn't seem to be working
the timer isn't the problem, the problem is (see line 34 and below) that it doesn't trace "correcto" when I click on the "verificar" button when the imput text has the right answer. please help, and please, again, consider that i'm new to programming. Any help is accepted, thank you. :)

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
stop()
var reloj:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startTimer);
reloj.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveHand);
reloj.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, endTimer);
function startTimer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    reloj.start();
    startButton.visible = false;
}
function moveHand(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    segundero.rotation = segundero.rotation + 6
}
function endTimer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace("Se agotó el tiempo");
    gotoAndPlay (1, "1");
}
nuevo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generarPregunta);
function generarPregunta(MouseEvent):void
{
    var random1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
    var random2:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
    var array:Array = new Array ("+","-","*","/")
    var randomIndex:int = Math.floor (Math.random()*4)
    SimbMat.text = array [ randomIndex ]
    numI.text = random1 + ""
    numD.text = random2 + ""
}
verificar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, verificarRespuesta);
function verificarRespuesta(MouseEvent):void
{
    if (String(SimbMat) == "+")
    {
        if (Number(numI.text) + Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text))
        {trace("correcto")}
        else
        {trace("incorrecto")}
    }
    else if (String(SimbMat) == "-")
    {
        if (Number(numI.text) - Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text))
        {trace("correcto")}
        else
        {trace("incorrecto")}
    }
    else if (String(SimbMat) == "*")
    {
        if (Number(numI.text) * Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text))
        {trace("correcto")}
        else
        {trace("incorrecto")}
    }
    else if (String(SimbMat) == "/")
    {
        if (Number(numI.text) / Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text))
        {trace("correcto")}
        else
        {trace("incorrecto")}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little error in your code which gives you the behavior that you'v got.

The error is when using the text field instead of its text in this repeatly used instruction :

```
if (String(SimbMat) == "sign")
```

which should be just : `SimbMat.text == "sign"` ( of course we don't need casting here because it's already a `String` ).

Also, try to avoid using many `if` statements when a simple [**`switch`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fce.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f5d) can do the job instead !

So you can do like this :

```
function verificarRespuesta(MouseEvent):void
{
    var sign:String = SimbMat.text;
    var correcto:Boolean = false;

    var num_I:Number = Number(numI.text),
        num_D:Number = Number(numD.text),
        imput:Number = Number(imput.text);

    // use a switch instead of many "if"
    switch (sign){

        case '+' :
            correcto = num_I + num_D == imput;
            break;

        case '-' :
            correcto = num_I - num_D == imput;
            break;

        case '*' :
            correcto = num_I * num_D == imput;
            break;

        case '/' :
            correcto = num_I / num_D == imput;
            break;          

    }

    trace(correcto ? 'Correcto !' : 'Incorrecto !');
    // you can also write it like this :
    /* 
        if(correcto){
            trace('Correcto !');
        } else {
            trace('Incorrecto !');
        }       
    */

}
```

You can take a look on this link about [Learning ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) from Adobe. Good Luck !

Hope that can help.